# Call a specific string from a class c#

Tags: c#, class, http, post, get

I want to parse the response of a HTTP POST Request -> I have the request processing in a separate class, I want to call it back to the main program. e.g. in Main program, I want to do Console.WriteLine(ResponseString) -> How would I call the response string from the class, into the Main program. Pictures included for reference:

[Parse it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLUio.png)

[Call it back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Xbd.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take the [tour], and please learn [ask] with a [mcve]. Please also do not post screenshots of your code and/or error messages (something to read: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2819245) and [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

The processing in your class will be within a function.  That function can return a string.

```
class Processing
{
    public string YourFunction()
    {
       //Do your request
       return your_result;
    }
}
```

Then in the Main program

```
var c = new Processing();
ResponseString = c.YourFunction();
```